# Concerned about how shower liner was installed

Tags: bathroom

My contractor installed shower liner, he will be adding corner dams, so I am sure if I should be concerned about how he handled outside corners. In right one he cut piece of the lining instead of wrapping it, not sure why and installed nail on the top of the threshold.

[image: 1]

On the left corner he didn't wrap liner around the stud.
[image: 2]
Are these non-issues if he installs corner dam? Or should another liner be installed?

Comment: If this is the only waterproofing layer? I would have issues with the screws in the top of the curb, although the water SHOULD not get that high in the shower, unless the drain clogs. The reason I ask this, I use the plastic pan as a hopefully redundant fail safe. I also use a liquid applied membrane over all the wet areas. 3 coats in the corners 2 coats on the walls and floor.

Comment: @Jack no, this is just shower liner. On the top of the shower floor and threshold there will be mortar and then cement board on walls and threshold, followed by liquid membrane line RedGuard.

Comment: Good deal, it is the same way I do.  I do not run any nails through the top of the curb like this guy did. I do, but kind of the same, but different. I set the cement board over the liner and drive the screws that hold the cement board onto the top of the curb with a big bed of silicone where the screws go through. The only other thing I do differently is I do not cut the corners of the liner. I make provisions in the framing and the liner perimeter baker to give the folded liner places to go without bulging everything out in the corners

Comment: I am not sure why he put nail in the curb, hopefully someone can chime in if it's an issue removing it.

Comment: Since it is getting a liquid applied waterproofing, the liner is a backup. It is still important to keep it intact. Silicone over the screw heads that are in the liner at the curb top will seal the screws in the picture. Again Lord willin' the PVC liner will never really be needed, and if the Redgard ever failed which should EVER amount to a pin hole leak only, the amount of water to ever get to the PVC liner SHOULD be so negligible, the liner will still be there to protect the framing.

Comment: I guess I can glue price of PVC liner to cover the screw in this case.

Comment: Put several inches of water in it and let it sit for at least 24 hours and check for water loss and leaks. That is how the inspector checked ours. After that they did the cement board, tile etc.

Comment: @Gil This is how it works for the shower base itself, but this on the top of the threshold to the shower.